# Give a different name to the executable other than the name of the executable script

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am using the following setup file to create executable using cx_freeze. Is it possible to generate the exe with a different name other than the name of the executable script?

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable 
import xlrd  
buildOptions = dict(                 
                 compressed = True,
                 optimize=2,                 
                 path=sys.path+[".\\uitls", “.\\supported”], 
                 include_files=[“Doc"],                 
                 includes=[“xlrd”, "win32com"],
                 packages=["utils", ”supported"],
                 append_script_to_exe=True,
                 copy_dependent_files=True,
                  ) 
setup(
                 name = "TestExecutable",
                 version = "0.1",
                 options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
                           executables = [Executable(script=r".\\codebase\\runner.py",
                           icon=".\\icon.ico",
                           base="Win32GUI")]                
     )
```

So now the exe which is created has name runner.exe and i want it to be something different like myexecutable.exe Renaming the executable, ir the script is not working cause the script is further referenced by the package modules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the `targetName` option:

```
executables = [Executable(targetName="myexecutable.exe")]
```

Comment: now it's called target_name (with the underscore)

Answer (score 1):

The new style of keyword is `target_name`

```
executables = [Executable(target_name="myexecutable.exe")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the keyword `"target_name"` inside  the
`Executable(target_name = "my_executable")`

keep the name of your executable file as per the OS `windows or linux`